# Como recibir parametro por url en laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

mi problema es que no puedo recibir 2 parametros enviados desde URL, (si puedo recibir 1 muy bien) el detalle es que al querer recibir 2 no se cómo poder hacerlo porque no me hala el valor que es, estos son mis archivos:

Web.php:

```
Route::get('creditos/{id}/edit/{val}','CreditoController@edit')->name('renuevacredito');
```

parte de mi archivo cliente.show:

```
<a href="/creditos/{{$cliente->id}}/edit/?deuda={{$cliente->total}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">
```

me lleva a esta ruta:

```
http://localhost:8000/creditos/22/edit/?deuda=210
```

donde el 22 es el id del cliente y la deuda que quiero halar 210 (hasta aqui todo bien)
pero al recibir los datos en el blade:

```
<input type="text" name="id_cliente" value="{{ app('request')->input('id') }}" readonly>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="descuento" class="form-control" value="{{ app('request')->input('deuda') }}" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
```

el id me aparece que tiene el valor "2" cuando debería tener "22"

y si lo coloco de esta forma:

```
<a href="/creditos/{{$cliente->id}}/edit/?deuda={{$cliente->total}}/?id2={{$cliente->id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Aplicar descuento y Renovar credito</a>
```

me aparece de esta otra en el input:

```
210/?id2=22
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es utilizar el helper "route" para generar las urls y, no más importante, utilizar las variables como las nombras en el archivo web.php

para que te funcione, utiliza este código:

```php
   <a href="{{route('renuevacredito',['id'=>$cliente->id, 'val'=>$cliente->total])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">
```

Fíjate que las variables las pasas con el mismo nombre que tienen en el archivo web.php

Espero que te haya ayudado